# How to get file path after saving using FileReference

Tags: actionscript-3

With the following code I save recorded sound to local place  that user select.
the thing I need is getting full path of the saved file.

```
function recordComplete(e:Event):void
{
    fileReference.save(recorder.output, "recording.wav");
    fileReference.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileSaved);  
}
function fileSaved(e:Event)
{
    trace("SAved");
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Unfortunately you can not get the saved file path using `FileReference` but if you are writing for AIR, you can use the [`File`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) class instead to get that ...

Comment: If this is an SWF running in the browser you cannot get a path to the end-users' directory. It's a security/trust issue (or call it feature). Why do you need the path? Maybe there's a workaround we can suggest...